# Looking for phrase to describe not understanding someone's misunderstanding

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a phrase that would describe it being more difficult to comprehend someone's misunderstanding of an idea or concept, once you yourself have understood it?

Comment: It sounds like a confusion between habitual (or learned) knowledge and self-evidence. It reminds me of the phrase "familiarity breeds contempt." Except that, here, it's more like "familiarity breeds detachment."

Comment: Your link gives a 'page not found' notification. Have you kept the illustrative text or can provide another example?

Comment: @Paul, edited question to remove link as the question appears to have been deleted

Comment: Something like “I don’t understand why you do t understand”?

Answer (score 1):

You could say ‘unconscious competence’.

https://medium.com/the-philosopher-s-guide-to-startups/unconscious-incompetence-ad5583abf646

1. Unconscious incompetence — when you’re doing something wrong and you don’t know you’re doing it wrong
2. Conscious incompetence — when you’re doing something wrong but you know you’re doing it wrong
3. Conscious competence — when you’re doing something right but you have to consciously focus on doing it the right way
4. Unconscious competence — when you’re doing something right and you don’t even have to think about it

(And, in 4. You have forgotten the steps you took to learn it).